# Joomla Image url changes - using no editor

Tags: html, joomla

Hi I'm building a site with Joomla 2.5.
I am using no editor for my articles because I need JS.
I have an image in my article with the path:

```
<img src="images/bar-closed.jpg" width="375px" height="36"/>
```

when i look at my src code in my browser it changes to:

```
<img src="/mysite4/images/bar-closed.jpg" width="375px" height="36"/>
```

Inserting the 'mysite4' directory.
Does anyone know why this is changing and how I can stop it from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your joomla under a subdirectory? If you want to prevent this just add a "/" before "images/bar-closed.jpg"

Comment: I do have 4 versions of the site in my htdocs folder. I've tried adding the '/' before the path which does stop the 'mysite4' directory from being inserted but my browser doesn't see the images at all.

Comment: Try setting the pages as subdomains linked to these subfolders.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go, will need to figure out how first! Could it be that I have multiple versions of the site in my htdocs folder? It looks like the images are now quickly appearing and then disappearing again on page load!! Not sure if I'll have to use absolute paths throughout?

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the SEF-plugin. It can be disabled (for the whole website) using the Plugin Manager. Its called *System - SEF*.

Comment: System SEF is currently turned on (Cache is off) - do I need to turn System SEF off? If so, does that mean all my paths have to be absolute? Thanks.

Comment: System - SEF needs to be turned off if you want to prevent the url from changing. I have never done this myself so I am not entirely sure, but I think it can cause problems to the rest of the site. But give it a try. The paths doesn't need to be absolute as long as there is no SEF routing done by the component. Why do you need to prevent this at all?

Comment: Images' urls don't have anything in common with Joomla's SEF.

Comment: Are you sure? What's plgSystemSef::onAfterRender doing then?

Comment: Thanks for your replys - unfortunately after turning the SEF off, ALL the images dissapeared. Seems my issue is only with a few images (perhaps the ones that are not in the main images folder but in another directory (in my case one of my templates folders). I've read somewhere that the order of the extensions in Joomla can effect the paths but I've tried everything!

Comment: My apologize. I've just checked, I hadn't expected joomla to rewrite "href's" and "src's"

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Move the joomla instance to parent directory
- Write .htacces rewrites in parent directory (not recommended)
- Create subdomain linked to the joomla subfolder
- Use absolute urls like www.your-domain.com/mysite4/images/bar-closed.jpg

BTW. Whats the point of your question? If you're using a few variants of joomla for development you'll have your production website under a final (sub)domain like www.example.com anyway. So it's **really doesn't matter** what relative urls are displayed in the source at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm finding it extremely frustrating. My images were all fine last week. I come to upload it and I had some issues with some images not displaying. I don't want to have to relink all the images with absolute paths after I've uploaded - that seems counter-productive. Weirdly on several of my pages the images load for a split second the disappear! WHat on earth is going on there!